# Two ESXi Servers, export/importing Snapshots?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

We have two servers, both with ESXi. Server A is used for every VM, and B is used for backups of the data of server A. 
At this the B server is used only for datastorage with backups of the data of server A.

Is it possible to clone a whole VM from server A to B on the fly? We checked out OVFtool, but that can't be done on the fly, because machine needs to be powered off.

We thought also of duplicate the datastorage of server A to B and then add when needed the VM on B to the Inventory. But we can't figure out how to copy from server A to B. 
Same for Snapshots, we couldn't figure out how to send a Snapshot van A to B.

Anyone tips or a solution regarding this issue?

The simple question is: how to clone *automatically* a VM from server A to server B on the Fly?

Comment: Have you checked "GhettoVCB", https://github.com/lamw/ghettoVCB ? By storing backup on a shared NFS and adding the restore process on B ( https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-10595 ) you should be able to achieve your goal.

Comment: Why don't you just set up an HA cluster between A and B?

Comment: Are these ESXi hosts managed by the same vCenter server?

Comment: @D34DM347 don't think ut vCenter Server, because I'm on the free tier